# Arranging formdata in a dictionary format without manual intervention

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, web-scraping, get

In different sites the formdata varies a lot. Some sites have got numerous requirements to be filled in through their form before allowing any scraper to reach the target page such as `ASP` sites. However, my question is how can those form be filled in as a dictionary so that it can be sent through `post` or `get` request parameter.

For example, the one below is such a formdata which should be sent through `post` request to get the valid response from a certain site. I collected it from chrome dev tools. I didn't see there any option so that I can collect it as a dictionary and place those as I did in my second example.

```
action:show_search_result
action_spam:dDfgEr
txtSearchType:5
txtPracName:
optSstate:1
optRegions:4
txtPcode:
txtShowBuildingType:0
optBuildingType:1
optHomeType:1
optBudget:
```

Organized data filled in parameters which I did it manually:

```
payload = {'action':'show_search_result','action_spam':'dDfgEr','txtSearchType':'5','txtPracName':'','optSstate':'1','optRegions':'4','txtPcode':'','txtShowBuildingType':'0','optBuildingType':'1','optHomeType':'1','optBudget':''}
```

I could only find two options. 1.`view URL encoded` 2. `view source` but none of these provides those parameters as dictionary. Is there any way to use it as a dictionary in the `post` or `get` request parameter without arranging manually?